# Could not pick a region and/or zone. when deploying a NodeJS managed vm app

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment, sdk, gcloud

While following the [App Engine Managed VM NodeJS tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world), I am now encountering an issue at deployment (see below).

Yesterday, I could successfully deploy. But today, with the same code and command, it fails. Anybody is encountering the same?

```
bash-3.2$ gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default
You are about to deploy the following modules:
 - test-node-mvm/default/20150603t163041  From: [/Users/steren/work/1-hello-world/app.yaml]
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Updating module [default]...Pushing image to Google Container Registry...
The push refers to a repository [gcr.io/_m_sdk/test-node-mvm.default.20150603t163041] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Updating module [default]...\Pushing repository gcr.io/_m_sdk/test-node-mvm.default.20150603t163041 (1 tags)
Image 511136ea3c5a already pushed, skipping
Updating module [default]...|Image 95b32d411fbe already pushed, skipping
Updating module [default].../Image 7a243a3158d4 already pushed, skipping
Image 1499561ab05e already pushed, skipping
Updating module [default]...-Image 4eb7c9d19de1 already pushed, skipping
Image fa0d484715ee already pushed, skipping
Updating module [default]...\Image 0c65fd2e1945 already pushed, skipping
Updating module [default]...|Image 869164a28a09 already pushed, skipping
Image ced2de04c271 already pushed, skipping
Updating module [default].../Image 834bcbba14e4 already pushed, skipping
Image badab73b83a3 already pushed, skipping
Updating module [default]...-Image f6323b382d0c already pushed, skipping
Updating module [default]...\Image 03bddf0f5129 already pushed, skipping
Image b9f524a60289 already pushed, skipping
Updating module [default]...|Image 21a9df37f3b1 already pushed, skipping
Image 54058f07b292 already pushed, skipping
Pushing tag for rev [54058f07b292] on {https://gcr.io/v1/repositories/_m_sdk/test-node-mvm.default.20150603t163041/tags/latest}
Updating module [default]...done.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Could not pick a region and/or zone. Deployed Version: 20150603t163041.384759778895867694
```

Comment: As Managed VMs are basically Compute Engine instances, it might be that your resources are exausthed in us-central region so it can allocate a new instance

Comment: Can you specify a `--zone` in your `gcloud` deploy command?

Answer (score 1):

Today I can successfully deploy with the same `gcloud` command.

I did not try to add `--zone`, but this may have been a solution.